# ECHO double single qoute

Tags: javascript, php, html

My php code inside HTML

```
$i = 1;
echo "<input type='text' class='uborder help-80percent' maxlength='3' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'' id='quantity_".$i."' onchange='updatetotalWeight(this.value, quantity_".$i.", current_quantity_".$i.", weight_".$i." )' />";
```

[image]

I want to make my:

```
updatetotalWeight(this.value, "quantity_1", "current_quanitity_1", "weight_1");
```

Do you have any idea how to make this thing become string?

Comment: I think your issue is the double single-quote after ``return isNumberKey(event)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use double quotes inside a double quoted string by escaping them with a backslash `\"`:

```
echo "<input type='text' class='uborder help-80percent' maxlength='3' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' id='quantity_".$i."' onchange='updatetotalWeight(this.value, \"quantity_".$i."\", \"current_quantity_".$i."\", \"weight_".$i."\" )' />";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes `\"`, also, you don't need to use string concatenation `.`, i.e.:

```
$i = 1;
echo "<input type='text' class='uborder help-80percent' maxlength='3' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'' id='quantity_$i' onchange='updatetotalWeight(this.value, \"quantity_$i\", \"current_quantity_$i\", \"weight_$i\" )' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try \ to scape the single quotes and surround the string using double quotes so you can you the benefits of interpolation.

```
   $var = "quotes";
   echo "i hate \'$var\'"; // outputs  "i hate quotes 'quotes'"
```

Basically try to avoid using '' . '' since it leads to a lot of confusion

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use HEREDOC to avoid all the need for escaping.

```
<?Php
   echo <<<HEREDOCNAME
The string starts here.
Literal second line of your output string. Your {$variable}. Or if you want to echo a {$_SESSION['variable']} or a {$_POST['variable']}.
   This would be another literal end line with a literal tab. No need for backslash-n or backslash-t.
Need to echo a "double quote"? Or a 'single quote'?
Another end line and below is how to end the HEREDOC (note that the end line must not have any space before the heredoc name):
HEREDOCNAME;
   // note that curly braces can also be used on:
   echo "My variable is {$variable}."
   // But never on single quotes.
   echo 'Single quotes should always be like this: '.$variable;
   // Nevertheless, you can also avoid concatenations and curly braces.
   echo "This is my $variable";
   // But things can get nasty if
   echo "Your string and $variableasdsad are a mixed mess.";
   // So
   echo "always{$use}proper{$escaping}. Because thing\$cangetnastyjustlike$that."
?>
```